# Ad mob ads not appearing in my new app?

Tags: android, admob

i developed an android app two days ago.During testing on emulator and real device it was showing test ads.but when i placed it on play store with real ads these ads are not appearing on my app.How much time it take to appear in newly added apps too display its first app.

Comment: were you using test ads before you publish it?if yes did you change it ?

Comment: Yes i change them all